# Actionscript calculates erroneous division without brackets

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math, division, brackets

Given this class definition:

```
package {
  public class Calc {
    public static function I(i:Number, s:Number):Number {
      var A:Number = helper_A(s);
      var B:Number = helper_B(s);
      var C:Number = helper_C(s);      
      return A * i + (Math.exp(B * i + C) - Math.exp(C) / B);
    }   
  }
}
```

Static functions `helper_A`, `helper_` B and `helper_C` do some math operations (One-liners with basic calculation and `Math.pow()`).

When calling this with

```
trace(Calc.I(27, 1985));
```

How is it possible that the following difference in brackets placement in the return statement of `function I` has an effect on the calculated outcome?

---

This version 1)

```
      return A * i + (Math.exp(B * i + C) - Math.exp(C) / B);
```

traces `0.01721552341268775`

---

While this version 2)

```
      return A * i + ((Math.exp(B * i + C) - Math.exp(C)) / B);
```

traces `0.017092065919602526`

---

From what I can tell, the result should be the same, mathematically. How come that Actionscript/Flash calculates the **erroneous** result without the brackets? Is there some weird internal caching, order, memory, foobar, ... thing going on here?

Comment: Your edit made the answers sound irrelevant and confusing. So I rolled back to original question. You should add your edit as a comment or append that with the original question, if you want. But do not delete the original texts, otherwise answers will look confusing.

Comment: Well, besides the edit I also voted for delete. This is, besides not a real question, surely a duplicate and of no use. Seems just like the brackets slipped my eyes.

Comment: But you can't delete it yourself. So it's better to keep the original text until it's deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(Math.exp(B * i + C) - Math.exp(C) / B);`

Without parentheses `Math.exp(C) / B` is executed first as division `/` has higher precedence than subtraction `-`.

`((Math.exp(B * i + C) - Math.exp(C)) / B);`

Here `(Math.exp(B * i + C) - Math.exp(C))` is executed first due to the parentheses, and then the result is divided by B. This is clearly different than the first version.

This is not anything related to AS3. This is well defined mathematical rule. Division, multiplication has higher precedence than addition, subtraction and parentheses is required to do addition, subtraction before multiplication, division.

Comment: Must have been debugging all sorts of stuff and got blind... obviously my brain was turned off :-o

Answer (score 0):

Check the operators [precedence](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fd1.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f6c) and by the way, you don't need the outer parentheses :

```
return A * i + (Math.exp(B * i + C) - Math.exp(C)) / B;
```